# Unable to start activity componentInfo Tablistener suddenly crashing the app

Tags: android, xml-parsing, tabs

So i'm getting this annoying problem. I'm pretty noob when it comes to android, so any help would be nice.

This is my MainActivity which seems to be crashing according to LogCat.
The app i'm trying to create must pull data from XML data, which i'm trying to get. Then from this data it must set the tabs name (that's what i'm trying to do).

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

private String uniqeAppId;
private ArrayList<StartupInfo> info;
private String ChannelTab;
private String VicinityTab;
private String CustomTab;
private String TrackingTab;
private String MoreTab;
public static Context appContext;
private DownloadXmlTask downloadxml = new DownloadXmlTask(this);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    info = new ArrayList<StartupInfo>();
    downloadxml.loadPage();
    appContext = getApplicationContext();
    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionbar.setTitle(uniqeAppId);

    ActionBar.Tab Frag1 = actionbar.newTab().setText(ChannelTab);
    ActionBar.Tab Frag2 = actionbar.newTab().setText(VicinityTab);
    ActionBar.Tab Frag3 = actionbar.newTab().setText(CustomTab);
    ActionBar.Tab Frag4 = actionbar.newTab().setText(TrackingTab);
    ActionBar.Tab Frag5 = actionbar.newTab().setText(MoreTab);

    Fragment Fragment1 = new Channeltab();
    Fragment Fragment2 = new Vicinitytab();
    Fragment Fragment3 = new Customtab();
    Fragment Fragment4 = new Trackingtab();
    Fragment Fragment5 = new Moretab();

    Frag1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(Fragment1));
    Frag2.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(Fragment2));
    Frag3.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(Fragment3));
    Frag4.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(Fragment4));
    Frag5.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(Fragment5));

    actionbar.addTab(Frag1);
    actionbar.addTab(Frag2);
    actionbar.addTab(Frag3);
    actionbar.addTab(Frag4);
    actionbar.addTab(Frag5);

}

public void GetTextForTabs(ArrayList<StartupInfo> info2) {
    this.info = info2;
    StartupInfo info3 = info.get(0);
    this.ChannelTab = info3.getChannelTab();
    this.VicinityTab = info3.getVicinityTab();
    this.CustomTab = info3.getCustomTab();
    this.TrackingTab = info3.getTrackingTab();
    this.MoreTab = info3.getMoreTab();

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


}

public void setInfo(ArrayList<StartupInfo> info) {
    this.info = info;

}

public void alert(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    public Fragment fragment;

    public MyTabListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

}
```

}

Then the LogCat:

[image: LogCat]

It seems to be the TabListener. But I don't understand why. It wasn't doing that earlier. It was when i tried to add data it started to crash. Can anyone help me here ?

Answer (score 2):

You have a null pointer exception at line 111 of your activity (in onTabSelected). It looks as though the null reference is probably to "fragment". Look at the section on "Performing fragment transactions":

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

This code will not fit your program exactly, but it gives you the general idea. You need to begin, do your add/replace/why and then commit.

By the by, since you are using ActionBarSherlock why not use the Support library so as to be able to support older versions of Android ?

Here is a simple example (it contains some superfluous stuff that you don't need) that might help:

```
public class ExtraContent extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
// Declare Tab Variable
com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab tab;

boolean mDebugLog = false;
String mDebugTag="ian_";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //mDebugLog = true;
    debugLog("ExtraContent onCreate" );

    // Create the actionbar
    com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();

    // Show Actionbar Home Icon (as normal)
    bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    // Show Actionbar Title (as normal)
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    // Create Actionbar Tabs
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    //enable home ...
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);     // ?
    bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);          // this is the one that enables home navigation

    //ib18 view for fragments ...
    setContentView(R.layout.extra_content);

    //create the fragment we want to use for display content
    Fragment ExtraLogin = new ExtraLogIn();


    // Create First Tab
    ActionBar.Tab tab0 = bar.newTab();
    tab0 = bar.newTab();
    tab0.setText("Unlock");
    tab0.setTabListener(new TabListener<ExtraTab0>(this, "tab0",ExtraTab0.class, null));
    bar.addTab(tab0);   

    // Create Second Tab
    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = bar.newTab();
    tab1 = bar.newTab();
    tab1.setText("Level 1");
    tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener<ExtraTab1>(this, "tab1",ExtraTab1.class, null));
    bar.addTab(tab1);        

    // Create Third Tab
    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = bar.newTab();
    tab2 = bar.newTab();
    tab2.setText("Level 2");
    tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener<ExtraTab2>(this, "tab2",ExtraTab2.class, null));
    bar.addTab(tab2);       


    if (savedInstanceState != null) { //if there is a saved bundle use it ...
        bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 0));
    }
    else {
        //ib18 savedInstanceState null so fti so start Login frag ...
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fb, ExtraLogin, "ExtraLogin").commit();
    }

}
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    debugLog("ExtraContent onMenuItemSelected" );
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuizLaunch.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    debugLog("ExtraContent onSaveInstanceState");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("tab", getSupportActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}

public class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    private final FragmentActivity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;
    private final Bundle mArgs;
    private Fragment mFragment;

    public TabListener (FragmentActivity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz,
            Bundle args) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
        mArgs = args;
        debugLog("ExtraContent TabListener" );
        FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
        // from a previously saved state. If so, deactivate it, because our
        // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
        mFragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);
        //
        if (mFragment != null && !mFragment.isDetached()) {
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
        ft.commit();
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        debugLog("ExtraContent onTabSelected");
        ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();

        if (mFragment == null) {
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(),mArgs);
            debugLog("adding fragment "+mTag );
            ft.add(R.id.tab, mFragment, mTag);    //ib18 add to "tab" holder
            ft.show(mFragment);  //ib1.6 show fragment ...
            ft.commit();
        } else {
            debugLog("attaching fragment "+mTag );
            ft.attach(mFragment);
            ft.show(mFragment);  //ib1.6 show fragment ...
            ft.commit();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        debugLog("ExtraContent onTabUnSelected");
        ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();

        if (mFragment != null) {   
            debugLog("hide and detach fragment "+mFragment );
            ft.hide(mFragment);  //ib1.6 hide fragment ...              
            ft.detach(mFragment);
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        debugLog("ExtraContent onTabReSelected");
    }

}

void debugLog(String message) {
    if (mDebugLog)
        Log.d(mDebugTag, message);
}
}
```

Comment: Chaning main activity to extend SherlockFragmentActivity, removed the old error but gave me a new one. Should I start a new question or just add it to here ?

Comment: You are probably supposed to open a new one, but this is fine for now ... I think a good approach is to try to start from a working example - I have posted one on my answer.